# Nginx configuration to cache angular app files

Tags: angularjs, nginx, cache-control

I have the following configuration to run an angular.js app, which works fine.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

But when I add cache

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|ico|mp4|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|css|js)$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, must-revalidate, s-maxage=2592000";
}
```

The files are not longer accesibles

```
[error] 5#5: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/scripts/vendor-1568b32f3e.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 87.63.75.163, server: localhost, request: "GET /scripts/vendor-1568b32f3e.js HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp", referrer: "http://myapp/auth/login"
```

Not sure why is trying to get the resources from `/etc/nginx/html/` when the root path is `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the "root" defined in the server section matches what you want.  Or define "root" under your regex location `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|ico|mp4|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|css|js)$`.  Without a root defined there nginx may be reverting to global definition under the server section.

Comment: basically define root in server block not location block